# MPMovieplayerController keeps download after stop (iphone)

Tags: iphone, download, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

When I stop the movie and the MPMovieplayerController is dismissed, I see in my router that the movie is continuing to download.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

This is, of course, not normal. What you can do is make a subclass of MPMoviePlayerController and override the `- (void) dealloc` function with the following code:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
   NSLog(@"My code is fine!");
}
```

Replace the MPMoviePlayerController in your code with your new custom subclass. Try watching a movie and dismissing it. If your application does not type `My code is fine!` into the console when you have dismissed it, then there's something wrong with your code. My guess is that you have assigned the movie player controller to a `strong` or `retain` property without setting it to nil. Make sure that (if you have self.movieController) you run `self.movieController = nil` after dismissing.

Also make sure that you have not added the movie player controller to any array or dictionary.